# not able to click on compose in gmail using selenium web driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have tried to compose mail, but I am not able to click on compose. I tried with the following code for compose mail

```
 import org.openqa.selenium.By;
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

 public class ComposeMail {

 public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://gmail.com");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    //enter the mail id
    driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("pulokjyotshnadas");
    //enter the password
    driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("xxxxx");;
    // click on signin button
    driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    // click on compose
   driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id=':hp']/div/div")).click();
```

I got the error:

> element not found

Comment: Are you sure ur xpath is correct? For me xpath is `.//*[@id=':id']/div/div`

Comment: yup @Surya is correct...my mistake...anyways u can also try it out with cssSelector `.aic>div>div`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below xapth:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'COMPOSE')]")).click();
```

In Gmail, ID is dynamic.

Comment: The html code for compose button in gmail is <div class="T-I J-J5-Ji T-I-KE L3" tabindex="0" role="button" style="-moz-user-select: none;" gh="cm">COMPOSE</div>. & i have also tried with driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'COMPOSE')]")).click(); still getting error of no element found

Comment: Hi it worked but we need to use explicit wait after that i tries this xpath. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using css selector as below , for me it worked fine.

```
 driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='T-I J-J5-Ji T-I-" +
                "KE L3']")).click();
```

Comment: If you use all these class names, it may work today, but defiantly going to break shortly!

Comment: Definitely it might break someday but i had this code return almost a year before and tried, till now it works fine!